# how to pass a static array in GPUImage filters?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpuimage

I want to use

```
filter.arrayValue = array[80];
```

in my .swift controller to input the array[80] to a GPUImage filter.

can someone give me an example how to implement this?

the following is how to pass a CGFloat to (texelWidth in) GPUImage Filter.

in .h

```
CGFloat texelWidthUniform;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGFloat leftEyeParameter;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize texelWidth = _texelWidth;

- (id)initWithFragmentShaderFromString:(NSString *)fragmentShaderString;
{
    .....

    texelWidthUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"texelWidth"];
    ....    
    return self;
}

- (void)setTexelWidth:(CGFloat)newValue;
{
    hasOverriddenImageSizeFactor = YES;
    _texelWidth = newValue;

    [self setFloat:_texelWidth forUniform:texelWidthUniform program:filterProgram];
}
```

Comment: your example is passing array to filter's shader file, not filter itself. do you mean that?